# BaseGameActivity and multiple inheritance

Tags: android, google-play-games

I want to use BaseGameActivity from the games examples:

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/master/BaseGameUtils/src/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/BaseGameActivity.java

but my game activity has to extend from another framework's activity class. Is there an implementation of BaseGameActivity factored out into a separate class so I don't have to have my activity inherit from it?

Thanks

Comment: the link is broken. [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/master/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/BaseGameActivity.java) it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no requirement to use exactly that `BaseGameActivity`. Create your own `BaseGameActivity` based on that source code but instead of

```
public abstract class BaseGameActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    GameHelper.GameHelperListener
```

put

```
public abstract class BaseGameActivity extends YourFrameworksActivity implements
    GameHelper.GameHelperListener
```

Answer (score 16):

BaseGameActivity is a pretty simple wrapper around [GameHelper](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/master/BaseGameUtils/src/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper.java), which is the object that really does all the work. If you can't derive from `BaseGameActivity`, simply use `GameHelper` directly. The [implementation](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/master/BaseGameUtils/src/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/BaseGameActivity.java) of the `BaseGameActivity` class can serve as an example of how to hook up the `GameHelper` methods to your Activity's lifecycle.

In summary:

- in your Activity's `onCreate`, create the `GameHelper` object.
- from your Activity's `onStart`, call GameHelper's `onStart`
- from your Activity's `onStop`, call GameHelper's `onStop`.
- from your Activity's `onActivityResult`, call GameHelper's `onActivityResult`.
- implement the `GameHelperListener` interface methods

Comment: would be nice to see some fragment based sample for this

Comment: @Tamas You can find another one of Bruno's answers on the topic of `Fragment`s [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16974527/844882).