# Google+ API Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-plus

I'm having trouble with converting my code to fragment

this is my code when my app is still an activity

```
package com.ronnielp.loginsample2;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SignIn extends Activity implements OnClickListener, 
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener{


    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 40;
    private PlusClient mPlusClient;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
    private TextView txtUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mPlusClient =new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
        .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)
        .setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity")
        .build();

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        txtUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUser);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        mPlusClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        mPlusClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mConnectionResult = result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Person user = mPlusClient.getCurrentPerson();
        String acc = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
        txtUser.setText(acc);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button &&  !mPlusClient.isConnected() && mConnectionResult !=null){
            try{
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
            } catch (SendIntentException e){
                mConnectionResult = null;
                mPlusClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            mConnectionResult = null;
            mPlusClient.connect();
        }
    }


}
```

and when i convert it to fragment my code doesnt work anymore
please help me I'm still a newbie in Android programming

Comment: you need to extend you activity to FragmentActivity, need to add this import SupportFragment (<android_folder>\extra\android\supporty\v4 ......) <-- i'm not sure about folder :S

Comment: Post your fragment code..

Comment: Are you using static or dynamic fragments ? Without code, all we can do is guess as to the possible cause of your problem.

Comment: sorry but ireally dont know static and dynamic fragments but I change the activity of that code to Fragment and my MainActivity XML has <fragment /> which is this activity

and it's working but my problem is when i click sign in button it doesnt connect

Comment: I dont have a fragment code it's only a normal activity and this code I only changed it to fragment and put it in mainactivity xml as <fragment/>

Comment: This might help to understand things better :-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974527/calling-google-play-game-services-from-a-fragment

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android google+ login in a fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217763/android-google-login-in-a-fragment)

Answer (score 3):

Number of thing may have gone wrong. One issue would be accessing your the childFragmentManager. The manager will not pass the result to the  fragment, you have to do that manually in your base Class.

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
      Fragment fragment = (Fragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(childTag);
      if(fragment != null){
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
      }
 }
```