# Is it correct to tie GoogleApiClient to Fragment lifecycle

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api-client, fragment-lifecycle

After using `startResolutionForResult`, onActivityResult method will be called within the Activity owning the Fragment, not within the Fragment itself. Also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16990087/1120126) says:

> The Google Play game services API should be tied to an Activity's
>   lifecycle, not a Fragment's lifecycle.

Is this also valid for GoogleApiClient?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its suggested that you [start a connection](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client#start_a_connection) in the Activity's `onCreate` method.